# Rails Record | Time since creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I find out how many hours have passed been since a record was created? I'm attempting to  sort with an algorithm and I need this amount as a variable. Thanks

Schema https://gist.github.com/1324803

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hours_since_creation = (Time.zone.now - @record.created_at) / 3600`